# Installing another instance of android studio on Mac

Tags: macos, android-studio

On a Mac, I have Android studio 1.2 installed.

I want another separate Android studio version 1.5.1 (the latest one) installed on my system.

Is it possible ? If yes, any leads on how to ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. I don't have any experience of installing android studio but I am using Mac and I have been doing like this with installing Xcode. Just give the name what your software version is and copy it in application. Hope you got it.